# ASP.NET MVC application with Angular mechanism - Buttons getting greyed out in some time

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

We are using ASP.NET MVC framework integrated with Angular mechanism and using SSO for authentication. On particular page, fields and buttons are getting frequently greyed out after some time. Refreshing the browser or clearing the browser cache helps in reducing the greyed out frequency.

How could this be handled permanently?

The buttons should not be greyed out after some time